# Blueimp jQuery File Uploader - Want the plugin to submit even if no file is chosen

Tags: jquery, forms, blueimp

I am using [Blueimp File Uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to upload files and submit a fields with the form. The file attachments are optional, so I want the **Submit** button to submit the form even if no file is queued for upload. In that case I would just capture the form fields that are being supplied.

How do I make the plug-in to work in the above fashion.

Comment: Please try with ng-angular, you can change its template easily and add more input values. http://realtica.github.io/ng-uploader/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternate to that.

Make the upload action different from form submit action.

Upload the files, and let the form return the uploaded file path, and then send them to the submitted form.